# Create diagonal line on top of box with background color in CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a diagonal line on top of the box that has background color green, as shown in example under. Which CSS should I use to do this?

[Diagonal line on top of green background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8xAu.png)

I managed to do it with this code:

```
.quote {
  background: #41ade5;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.quote:before {
  background: inherit;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  content: '' !important;
  display: block !important;
  height: 50% !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  transform: skewY(1.5deg) !important;
  transform-origin: 100% 0 !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  top: 0;
}`
```

But then the diagonal line got many edges, and not sharp. Shown in image below:

[Diagonal line with edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G8C1.png)

Does anyone have any good CSS tips for making a diagonal line that is more clean?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: solid 1px black; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px; background: green; margin-bottom: 200px; transform: rotate(174deg); position: absolute; left: -77px; top: -15px; ">

  </div>
</div>
```

Did you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this look any better for you. I have just added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`, which is known to help reduce jaggies. However I think that solution is only when no anti-aliasing is being applied. It might be the case that this as good as the browsers anti-aliasing gets.

```css
body {
background:#000;
}
.quote {
  background: #41ade5;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.quote:before {
  background: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(1.5deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you draw an image it will take edge and unsharp but css does not.

Below is your css code and it's working fine.

```css
.quote {
  background: #41ade5;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.quote:before {
  background: black;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  content: '' !important;
  display: block !important;
  height: 50% !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  transform: skewY(1.5deg) !important;
  transform-origin: 100% 0 !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote"></div>
```